# confused about my user name (jgrau = 95710?) and how the site works

Tags: support, status-completed, ubuntu-community

I'm confused how this site works, because I only find editing on my questions but can not recognize the answer to my originally posted issue:

> My issue is that I can't get sound to my TV which I connected via HDMI
>   cable to my HP Pavilion g6 Laptop running under OS Ubuntu 12.04-64bit.

I posted, in response to Matthew's answer

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4UCV.png]

and

> Terminal output for aplay shows two video devices

jg-laptop@JG-Laptop:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
jg-laptop@JG-Laptop:~$

OR

> jg-laptop@JG-Laptop:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
>    0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
>                         HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0544000 irq 44
>    1 [Generic_1      ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
>                         HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0540000 irq 16

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4UCV.png

Comment: Other account for merging: http://askubuntu.com/users/95478/jgrau

Comment: I cannot see [this image](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/109765435561724337623/albums/posts/5797395730233476786?hl=en), which is linked to in the question. You may want to alter or remove that link from this meta question.

Comment: It's on this post now, I hope so at least...                                           Can somebody explain to me what I would have to do to get the sound through the HDMI connection to my TV?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have registered two accounts - you have created a question using one account but were trying to edit/answer using your other account.

I have now merged both accounts - you should be able now to edit your questions.